# How to set the background color for the selected XAML node in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2012, themes

I have downloaded the VS2012 theme designer and am using a dark theme. In the designer I click on the WPF element in the designer and the corresponding text element in the XAML code editor should be selected. However the normal background color of the editor is dark dark grey and the background color of the selected item seems to be black. There is little or no contrast.

My question is, out of the hundreds of elements in the theme designer does anybody know the correct one to change to fix this problem?

Answer (score 8):

In VS 2013, which I assume is the same as VS 2012, it is sufficient to click

Tools -> Options -> Fonts and Colors -> Text Editor -> Inactive Selected Text

and set the set the colors for that element type.

Answer (score 1):

First create (or download and import) a custom theme. Then you need two steps to change the color:

1. Set the color in the theme designer: Text Editor → Inactive Selected Text → Background. Save it and apply your custom theme by double click.
2. Select: Tools -> Options -> Fonts and Colors -> Text Editor -> Inactive Selected Text -> Item Background -> Default

Every time you change the color in the theme designer, the 2nd step has to be repeated. Maybe it's sufficient to do only the 2nd step, but I did not try it.